# How can I see fastapi validation errors in pytest output?

Tags: pytest, fastapi

When developing tests, I often get 422 errors. However, I can't see the exception thrown on the server in the pytest output. Without the exception details, it makes tracking down the error fairly difficult. Is there some way I can get these errors displayed in the pytest output?

Comment: You can give an additional parameter to your asserts that contain the body of the error message - `assert response.status_code == 200, response.text()`. Does that work for you? (I usually wrap this in a `get_200` or `post_200` fixture that ensures the correct response type (which in turn depends on the test client fixture)

Comment: That certainly helps, but what I'd really like to see is the full stack trace. (Also, for posterity, it's response.text, not response.text())

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2799 btw? It gives a few possible solutions of how you could approach this